# Can CSS be used to crop off the edges of images based solely on img.class (with no added containers)?

Tags: css, image, border, crop

A large number of images have had various colored borders applied to them within the image files themselves.

Is there a way to use CSS to effectively crop their edges off so that a new, consistent border can be applied to all these images via styles?

```
<p class="score-title"> 
<img class="cover-image" .../>
...
</p>
```

I would want to cut 5 pixels off all four sides of each image, and then add a CSS border of my own.

5 pixels would be enough to remove all the diverse borders without noticeably cutting into the images much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the `border` property together with `box-sizing:border-box` - this will replace the outer pixels of your image with the new css defined border.

```css
.cover-image {
  border: 5px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img class="cover-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food" alt="" />
```